# setFilterPredicate on a NSArrayController doesn't work if it's in "Auto Rearrange Content"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have a classic CoreData application, displaying it's data in NSTableView with Binding (all done with XCode 4.2).

Working fine until I decide yesterday to check, in Attributes Inspector, the 'Auto Rearrange Content' for the ArrayController. Now, when I try to set the filter predicate on it, I get:

```
[<_NSFaultingMutableSet 0x102b65950> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: name
```

Keep in mind that without this option it work perfectly: the predicate is good and the controller is properly filtering it's managed content, and the table view is displaying only the entity that match the predicate.

Of course I could just de-enable this "auto rearrange content" but it is useful for maintaining the sort order in the event of a change in entities. If I edit one entity, the "date modified" change, and since my sort order is on this date I want the TableView to re-order it's line automatically. And it does with this option, but alas with added bug of "addObserver not supported".

The _NSFaultingMutableSet come from a to-many relationship in the concerned entity, hence the "Set". Maybe "Auto Rearrange Content" isn't compatible with "setFilterPredicate" with a to-many relationship ?

Anybody having similar problem ? An internal bug of NSArrayController ?

**Note**: the predicates that cause problem are of the form

```
name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR ANY aliases.name CONTAINS[cd] %@
```

or

```
ANY tags.name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR ANY tags.aliases.name CONTAINS[cd] %@
```

it's seems that the 'ANY' is causing some conflict...

Comment: Apparently I need to use subqueries whenever I walk a keypath across a to-many relationship ? see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3646030/1040553

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution, with the above comment on SUBQUERY.

Keep the option 'auto rearrange content' but change the predicate to:

```
name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR SUBQUERY(aliases, $anAlias, $anAlias.name CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count != 0
```

and

```
SUBQUERY(tags, $aTag, $aTag.name CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count !=0 OR SUBQUERY(tags, $aTag, $aTag.aliases.name CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count !=0
```

Respectively.

Probably the predicate were wrong, I just didn't run into others problems before.